# Confusion about mutable and immutable set in scala

Tags: scala

Hello I am new to scala and I am confused about method set.+(element).
when I do this

```
var set_1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int](2)
set_1.+=(1)
println(set_1)

val set_1: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int](2)
set_1.+=(1)
println(set_1)
```

I get result as `Set(1, 2)` for both of them. First one I used "var" and "immutable", second one I used "val" and "mutable". What is mechanism of .+() method? It reassign the variable set_1 or modify the value of set_1?
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you're using an immutable set but you're storing it in a var. When you call "+=" the result is analogous to the following except instead of creating a new variable set2 you are storing the new set in the variable set1...

```
val set1 = Set(2)
val set2 = set1 + Set(1)
```

The original Set(2) is never modified, instead a new set is created. That new set is then assigned as the value of the mutable variable set1.

In the second case the variable set1 points to a mutable set. You create the set Set(1), then modify that same set to contain Set(1,2)

There are use cases for both, but personally I would use the immutable set most of the time as it is easier to reason about.

Comment: that is what i guess. Thank you very much.

Comment: For "effectively doing" see http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators  It's confusing because the first example is usually expressed as infix, but the syntax doesn't affect the desugaring.

Comment: Thanks for noting this. I've rephrased the answer to make it clear that the code is just an analogy and doesn't match the desugaring exactly

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, the first example should not compile. `=+` in this case is an operator, applied to the `var set_1`, but `set_1.+=` syntax makes it look like a regular method call on the instance `set_1` is referring to. This is what causes the confusion.

Comment: Do you know what is the purpose of the .+= syntax is (with the dot)?  Is it possible to do that for all operators?

Comment: `<object>.foo` usually just means "call method `foo` on `<object>`" (on `immutable.Set`, `+=` is just a regular method name). That's exactly why I think the first example should not compile.

Comment: @Dima but it can be compiled, you can try it by yourself. So I think .+= can be ragarded as += in first case.

Comment: I know, it can be compiled. I am just saying, that it should not.

Comment: Here's the link. The desugaring follows normal selection; it doesn't care whether it's expressed as infix notation. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators

Comment: Yeah ... seems like somebody overthought this big time ;)

Comment: While a lot of the syntactic magic in Scala is indeed confusing, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Ben what do you mean "not an answer to the question"??? If "=+ in this case is an operator, applied to the var set_1" does not answer the question, then WHAT DO YOU THINK DOES???

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11627304)

Comment: @NikolayFominyh what do you mean "not an answer to the question"??? If "=+ in this case is an operator, applied to the var set_1" does not answer the question, then WHAT DO YOU THINK DOES???

Comment: @NikolayFominyh what does "Russian bears honor code" say about criticizing without suggesting something better, ah?

Comment: @Dima, sorry. It's from review rage. Was confused by start of answer. :) I have not downvoted BTW. Will be more accurate next time.